# Why is this javascript not moving through properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, slideshow, src

I have some lines of code that should function like a slide show my problem is that is will only go to the first image in the array but stops and shows an error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'src' of undefined or null reference Carousel_JavaScript.js, line 48 character 5.

```
var ilist = document.images;
var iarray=["voulenteering.jpg","event_diner.jpg","fireworks.jpg"];

for(var i = 0; i < iarray.length; i++) 
{
    ilist[i].src = "../../images/"+iarray[i]
}

function slideit()
{
    var step=0
    var whichimage=0
    if (!document.images)
        return
    document.images.slide.src=eval("ilist"+step+".src")
    whichimage=step
    if (step<3)
        step++
    else
        step=0
    setTimeout("slideit()",3500)
}
slideit()

function slidelink()
{
    if (whichimage >0)
        window.location="../../redirect.html"
}
```

if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.
I know for a fact that there is nothing wrong with the path.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Sounds like you don't have more than 1 `<img>` tag in your page.

Comment: We don't need or want to see your attempts at debugging (console.log, etc.) Also, voulenteering?

Comment: Well I do only have one <img> tag in the html. the idea is that the one <img> tag's src will change.


<div class="corouselContainer">
 <span class="link">
     <a href="javascript:slidelink()" class="link">
        </a>
     <a href="javascript:slidelink()" class="link">
         <img src="../../images/image_not_available.png" name="slide" width="700" height="200" border="5" />
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
<script language="javascript" src="Carousel_JavaScript.js"></script>

Comment: @LeeTaylor how about some help.

Answer (score 0):

your variable `whichimage` is declared only function `slidit()`, but as I can see in your code, you also want to use that variable in another function, in which at that moment that variable always is `undefined`. To fix that, you need move your `whichimage` declaration before `slideit()` function and inside your function only set that variable to 0.

Comment: good idea but I tried that and I got the same result and same error. any other ideas?